# Can't append a list of dicts with dict from another list of dicts

Tags: python, mysql-python

Been Googling hours again for answer but seems like my situation is unique, or my understanding of Py is...uh, unique.

I have a list of dictionaries (let's call it sqlListOfDict) built from MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor query, Py print yields this:

```
[{'volYtday': 18083292,
  'volToday': 49395261,
  'time': datetime.timedelta(0, 34800),
  'priceChgPct': Decimal('1.2400'),
  'volDiffPct': 173.15414140301445,
  'priceNom': Decimal('6.5300'),
  'date': datetime.date(2013, 4, 30),
  'secCode': 'xoxoxo',
  'volDiff': 31311969}]
```

Then I have another list of dictionaries (let's call it myListOfDict), declared empty, Py print yields this:

```
[{'priceChgPct': '',
  'volYtday': '',
  'priceNom': '',
  'volDiffPct': '',
  'volToday': '',
  'time': '',
  'date': '',
  'secCode': '',
  'volDiff': ''}]
```

I need to append myListOfDict with a specific dictionary from sqlListOfDict by index number, the code:

```
myListOfDict.append(sqlListOfDict[0])
```

No joy, myListOfDict is still as declared (empty) and Py doesn't give any traceback.

I did some experiments:

```
listDictA = [dict.fromkeys(['secCode', 'volDiff'])]

listDictB = [{'secCode': 'valB1', 'volDiff': 1000},
             {'secCode': 'valB2', 'volDiff': 1000},
             {'secCode': 'valB3', 'volDiff': 1000},
             {'secCode': 'valB4', 'volDiff': 1000},
             {'secCode': 'valB5', 'volDiff': 1000},
             {'secCode': 'valA1', 'volDiff': 1000}]
```

Ran the same command:

```
listDictA.append(listDictB[0])
```

It worked! What did I do wrong for the first case? Thanks for helping.

Comment: Can you share the actual code you have?

Comment: Now that I think a little more about it. You could print out a row without calling .fetchone()...

Comment: Hi Martin, which actual code do you mean? Thanks.

Comment: The code that produces `sqlListOfDict`. Also, what *output* are you expecting?

Comment: Hi Jason, exactly. 'print sqlListOfDict[i]['anyKey']' gives no grief. Do I need to do thing differently for append? Thanks.

Comment: What's your version of python? `A.append(B[0])` works perfectly for me on 2.7.3.

Comment: Hi Marc, I'm running python27-2.7.3_6 on FreeBSD 9.1-RELEASE-p3 #0. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're expecting that the first item in `myListOfDict` is filled up with values from the first entry in `sqlListOfDict`.

You say that `myListOfDict` is *declared empty*, but the fact is that you don't need that kind of declaration.  In Python, you can append whatever objects you like to a list, without any declaration of what types go into it.

I'll simplify your example a bit, and hope that clears it up:

```
>>> myListOfDict = []  # create an empty list
>>> sqlListOfDict = [{'volYtday': 18083292,
                      'volToday': 49395261}]
>>> myListOfDict.append(sqlListOfDict[0])
>>> myListOfDict
[{'volYtday': 18083292, 'volToday': 49395261}]
```

Also, if you're dealing with two lists, you might want to consider extending the first list with the second, instead of append only the first item.

```
>>> myListOfDict.extend(sqlListOfDict)
```